# Questions about native calltrace using Java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, windbg

We're debugging an error that causing a crash in a Tomcat web application.
The application uses 2 3rd-party apps over jni, one of the 3rd-parties using SmartHeap (it is a memory management library for c/c++ applications), the other don't (it is webMethods broker version 5).

The strange thing is I see in the crash log that webMethods calls its native methods to initiate a connection to the broker server, but if I print the call trace of the thread where the crash happened using WinDbg (loading the minidump file created when the JVM crashed), it contains calls to SmartHeap functions. Now i feel I'm a bit lost... because I've checked, and found no references to this dll from the webMethods binaries.

(actually a memory allocation is called)

My question is how is it possible?

I mean anybody could describe how this part is working? Because I thought that the interpreted/compiled and native frames are called in a fixed order (it is logical).

- maybe the call stack is invalid? (now we have many dump files with almost the same call trace)
- or the call trace (the calling order of the native functions) is valid, only some of the functions have been reordered before calling (like a lazy object has to be generated before sending it to the webMethods broker, but i don't see any sign of this)

I'm querying the call trace on the dump file by calling ".ecxr" and "kv", the output is:

```
0:060> .ecxr
eax=4d330554 ebx=4d350010 ecx=4d330010 edx=00000000 esi=4d350010 edi=00000000
eip=4c912f15 esp=4bf1dad0 ebp=3574884d iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010206
shsmp!shi_allocSmall2+0x195:
4c912f15 8b4d00          mov     ecx,dword ptr [ebp]  ss:0023:3574884d=????????
0:060> k
*** Stack trace for last set context - .thread/.cxr resets it
ChildEBP RetAddr  
4bf1daec 4c912bbd shsmp!shi_allocSmall2+0x195
4bf1dafc 4c91b973 shsmp!MemAllocPtr+0x5d
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for awssl50jn.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for awssl50jn.dll - 
4bf1db14 49abc38d shsmp!shi_malloc_dbg+0x23
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
4bf1db3c 49abeca2 awssl50jn!Java_COM_activesw_api_client_ssl_AwSSLNative_getSecurityInfo+0xa1cd
4bf1db48 49ab5e66 awssl50jn!Java_COM_activesw_api_client_ssl_AwSSLNative_getSecurityInfo+0xcae2
4bf1db4c 49ab5e55 awssl50jn!Java_COM_activesw_api_client_ssl_AwSSLNative_getSecurityInfo+0x3ca6
4bf1db60 49ab667d awssl50jn!Java_COM_activesw_api_client_ssl_AwSSLNative_getSecurityInfo+0x3c95
4bf1db80 49abdbbc awssl50jn!Java_COM_activesw_api_client_ssl_AwSSLNative_getSecurityInfo+0x44bd
4bf1dc20 4c912f4f awssl50jn!Java_COM_activesw_api_client_ssl_AwSSLNative_getSecurityInfo+0xb9fc
4bf1dc78 49abd607 shsmp!shi_allocSmall2+0x1cf
00000000 00000000 awssl50jn!Java_COM_activesw_api_client_ssl_AwSSLNative_getSecurityInfo+0xb447`
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps SmartHeap has a 'feature' of inserting itself as the one and only allocator for the process?

Comment: Could you post the output of `~#s;.exr -1;kv`? How did you check for references?

Comment: @Thomas, I've checked the output of the above command, and it prints the following:

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for your reply! I've checked the output of the above command, and it prints the correct data about the exception, but the call trace belongs to the writing of the minidump file (it contains this: dbghelp!MiniDumpWriteDump+0x2470), it doesn't contain any rows that belongs to the function mentioned in the exception report. I think it is because first we have to switch to the right thread, and it seems `.ecxr` does this. (sorry, I was over the 5 minutes, i'm new here...)

Comment: thanks @bmargulies, I think because the JVM is working, and it uses MSVCR100.dll, it cannot be true, but I'll ask them about this just to be sure... already asked Software AG about webMethods using SmartHeap or not, but because it is an ancient version, they couldn't give me informations (I think they bought wM from version 6, so they may really don't have info about this)

Comment: This looks much like you have registered your own unhandled exception handler and call `MiniDumpWriteDump()` on your own. Doing `~#s` should select the thread with the exception, if the dump was taken by the OS itself. I could imagine that the exception is swallowed in your case and therefore we cannot approach it like this.

Comment: I think the JVM, or Tomcat registered this exception handler to be able to generate the dump file on a crash. So you're saying the call trace maybe invalid?